List of employee not displaying on my Web Application with Servlet, Tomcat, MySQL and JSP
```My list Employee` method from my Controller is not showing the records in JSP file
Img file1 
Image file2
controller method
private void listEmployee(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws SQLException, IOException, ServletException {
    List<Employee> employees = employeeDAO.getAllEmployee();
    request.setAttribute("employees", employees);
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("Employee.jsp");
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);

}

DAO
public List getAllEmployee() {
    try {

        Configuration cfg = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
        SessionFactory sf = cfg.addAnnotatedClass(Employee.class).buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sf.getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Query<Employee> q = session.createQuery("from Employee");
        List<Employee> employee = q.getResultList();
        System.out.println("Records retrieved : " + employee);
        
    } catch (HibernateException e) {

        System.out.print(e);
    }
    return null;
  
}

JSP File
       <c:forEach items="${employees.rows}" var="employees">
                         <tr>
                    <td><c:out value="${employees.empid}"/></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${employees.firstName}"/></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${employees.lastName}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${employees.department}"/></td>
                    
                    </tr>
                     </c:forEach>


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Make sure you understand the purpose of each line of getAllEmployee(). Then the cause of the problem will become apparent.

var="employee" without plural s.

You forgot to tell/confirm whether System.out.println("Records retrieved : " + employee); printed the desired result. If it doesn't then it's absolutely not a Tomcat/Servlet/JSP related problem and you should remove that noise from the question. If it does, then you should reduce the reproducer to plain JSP/Servlet with a stubbed List instead of bringing the whole Hibernate noise into the question. And, System.out.print(e); is absolutely a bad idea. Never do this. Let that exception go. You will then end up receiving in webbrowser a normal error page with the entire answer therein.

Thanks everyone. I already solved the problem in a different way. I added this code to my JSP file and remove the listemployee method from controller.
<sql:query var ="result" dataSource="hibernatemysql">
select * from employee
</sql:query>
